# Best practice: Write directly to file vs write to stdout

Tags: file, io, stdout

Per the title, would it be considered a better practice to write directly to a file, or write to stdout by default to support piping. Contextually, this would be a simple one script app.

E.g.
Args with the csv file as the first arg

```
python write_file.py foo.csv
```

versus no args, with a pipe to a csv

```
python write_file.py > foo.csv
```

I am not asking how to implement either solution, I am just wondering which would be 'better' in a general sense.